# the procedure entry point TaskDialog could not be located

Tags: c++

I am compiling a C++ program with MinGW-w64 provided by MSYS2 using makefiles generated by CMake.
My program works perfectly with other compilers (Clang, MSVC) but when compiled with G++ it throws me the following error:
`the procedure entry point TaskDialog could not be located in the dynamic link library path/to/my/executable.exe`.

I've seen similar problems on other questions, but none of the solutions provided in those posts worked.

I think this is because the TaskDialog function is in some DLLs that MinGW cannot find. However, I am linking with `Comctl32.lib` statically and it seem to work fine on other compilers.

What should I do to solve this problem? Or at least is there anything I can try and do to see what happens?

**EDIT**: just to clarify, my program compiles and links with no errors, but as soon as I run it I see a dialog that looks like this: [image]

**EDIT2**: Updated to include a minimal reproducible example
main.cpp:

```cpp
#pragma comment(linker, "\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
  TaskDialog(nullptr, nullptr, L"Title", L"Instruction", L"Content",
             TDCBF_OK_BUTTON, TD_INFORMATION_ICON, nullptr);
  return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(Test)

add_executable(Test WIN32 main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Test comctl32.lib)
```

Run command:

```
cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -S/path/to/source -B/path/to/build -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

then
`cmake --build /path/to/build --config Debug --target Test -j 10 --`
Run the built executable **FROM THE EXPLORER**. The error window doesn't show when you run from the console for some reason.

Comment: What does your cmakelists.txt look like? Does it work if you compile from the terminal?

Comment: Here is a wild, but educated, guess. open `MinGW/Include/commctrl.h` and find the line `/* define _WIN32_IE if you really want it */` and change below to `#if 1` and `#define _WIN32_IE   0x0500`. Unless you do so, there will be a lot of constants not defined (which I suspect is what is causing the entry point error for taskdialog) I ran into a number of those issue in [This github project](https://github.com/drankinatty/winsolver). See the section on **Compiling with MinGW**. (you may need to adjust for MinGW-64, but you may not)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I couldn't find the lines you talked about, but I did try and define _WIN32_IE as 0x0500. The same thing happens.

Comment: Nothing ventured, nothing gained. I don't know why MinGW has such difficulty with commctrl, but you are not the first. Sorry it wasn't the silver bullet. What does your CMakeLists.txt look like (or at least what is the resulting compiler string for g++?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've updated my post to contain a minimal reproducible example. I am quite suspicious of the code at the top of `main.cpp` since I have no idea what it does, and if I don't include that `#pragma comment` then it will give me an error saying 'ordinal not found in dll' or something like that.

Comment: @user17732522 I have updated my post to contain a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have updated my post to contain a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You explicitly spelling `.lib` is suspicious. MinGW names it `libcomctl32.a`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I removed the `.lib` and the same thing happens.